# Should be valid to one and only one of schema, but more than one are valid error

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Im trying to create a json schema for following object models. But im getting following error when trying to validate data against the schemas.

```
should be valid to one and only one of schema, but more than one are valid: {"$ref":"#/$defs/drug-treatment"}{"$ref":"#/$defs/surgery-treatment"}
```

below is my schema

```
{
  "$id": "someid",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "description": "JSON Schema for treatments",
  "oneOf" : [
    { "$ref" : "#/$defs/drug-treatment" },
    { "$ref" : "#/$defs/surgery-treatment" }
  ],
  "$defs": {
    "base": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type-tag": {
          "enum": [ "SURGERY", "DRUGTREATMENT", "RADIOLOGY", "PHYSIOTHERAPY" ]
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uuid"
        },
        "patient-id": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uuid"
        },
        "patient-name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "provider-id": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uuid"
        },
        "provider-name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "diagnosis": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "followup-treatments": {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : { "$ref" : "#" }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "id",
        "type-tag",
        "patient-id",
        "patient-name",
        "provider-id",
        "provider-name",
        "diagnosis",
        "followup-treatments"
      ]
    },
    "drug-treatment": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref" : "#/$defs/base" }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "drug": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "dosage": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "start-date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "end-date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "frequency": "integer"
      },
      "required": [
        "drug",
        "dosage",
        "start-date",
        "end-date",
        "frequency"
      ],
      "unevaluatedProperties" : false
    },
    "surgery-treatment": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref" : "#/$defs/base" }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "surgery-date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "discharge-instructions": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "required": [
          "surgery-date",
          "discharge-instructions"
        ],
        "unevaluatedProperties" : false
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Here is sample data that im validating agains the schema.

```
"treatments": [
    {
      "type-tag": "DRUGTREATMENT",
      "drug": "fdsds",
      "dosage": 2.0,
      "start-date": "2222-02-12",
      "end-date": "2222-02-12",
      "frequency": 2,
      "id": "aa7da984-0252-45b1-b0cd-f1dbe98662e2",
      "patient-id": "ab62420e-0bd8-4e39-8e0b-36e464b7abb2",
      "patient-name": "Tom",
      "provider-id": "154523b2-7598-4ed4-aab1-b2ef1692109c",
      "provider-name": "gdsfdsd",
      "diagnosis": "sfdsfds",
      "followup-treatments": []
    },
    {
      "type-tag": "SURGERY",
      "surgery-date": "2222-02-12",
      "discharge-instructions": "dsfdsfdsfds",
      "id": "12d2e565-8966-4029-840b-1959277b37f6",
      "patient-id": "ab62420e-0bd8-4e39-8e0b-36e464b7abb2",
      "patient-name": "Tom",
      "provider-id": "154523b2-7598-4ed4-aab1-b2ef1692109c",
      "provider-name": "gdsfdsd",
      "diagnosis": "fdsfds",
      "followup-treatments": [],
    }

  ]
```

but when im validating the type "DRUGTREATMENT" its giving me the error

```
should be valid to one and only one of schema, but more than one are valid: {"$ref":"#/$defs/drug-treatment"}{"$ref":"#/$defs/surgery-treatment"}
```

any idea whats Im missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I made some corrections to your schema but this should work for the sample data from your question. Your schema has some syntax errors and wrongly placed keywords:

```
{
  "$id": "someid",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "treatments": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/treatment-item"
      }
    }
  },
  "$defs": {
    "treatment-item": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/drug-treatment"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/surgery-treatment"
        }
      ]
    },
    "base": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type-tag": {
          "enum": [
            "SURGERY",
            "DRUGTREATMENT",
            "RADIOLOGY",
            "PHYSIOTHERAPY"
          ]
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uuid"
        },
        "patient-id": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uuid"
        },
        "patient-name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "provider-id": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uuid"
        },
        "provider-name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "diagnosis": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "followup-treatments": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/treatment-item"
          },
          "minItems": 0
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "id",
        "type-tag",
        "patient-id",
        "patient-name",
        "provider-id",
        "provider-name",
        "diagnosis",
        "followup-treatments"
      ]
    },
    "drug-treatment": {
      "allOf": [ { "$ref": "#/$defs/base" } ],
      "properties": {
        "drug": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "dosage": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "start-date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "end-date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "frequency": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "drug",
        "dosage",
        "start-date",
        "end-date",
        "frequency"
      ],
      "unevaluatedProperties": false
    },
    "surgery-treatment": {
      "allOf": [ { "$ref": "#/$defs/base" } ],
      "properties": {
        "surgery-date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "discharge-instructions": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "unevaluatedProperties": false
      },
      "required": [ "surgery-date", "discharge-instructions" ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Showing error message with an arbitrary additional property.

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. This stops complaning about the more than one valid schema error but it does not validate the data at all now. for example if I give something like {
      "type-tag": "DRUGTREATMENT",
      "drug": "fdsds",
      "start-date": "2222-02-12"
    }. This will validate success even though lots of missing fields

Comment: What validator are you using? Maybe the validation is not working as it should be. I added a screenshot showing the validation error if I add an arbitrary property.

Comment: Im using networknt json-schema-validator. do you mind telling me which one you are using ?

Comment: I am using the validator in JSONBuddy (https://www.json-buddy.com).